# how to upgrade local variable to be an extension method

Tags: c#, .net

**How do we upgrade a predicate to be part of an extension method and use it inside of our Linq clauses?**

I've defined a predicate and am able to succesfully use it:

```
Func<BlobsPerContainerModel, bool> isOutgoingContainer = x => x.Container.StartsWith("outgoing-");
var outgoingBlobsContainer = blobsPerContainer.Where(isOutgoingContainer).ToList();
```

Rather than defining that predicate in the same spot, I'd like to upgrade it into its own `Extensions` class.

I've placed the code inside a class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Func<BlobsPerContainerModel, bool> isOutgoingContainer(this BlobsPerContainerModel b) => x => b.Container.StartsWith("outgoing-");
}
```

However, when attempting to use it this way:

```
var outgoingBlobsContainer = blobsPerContainer.Where(isOutgoingContainer).ToList();
```

I'm getting this:

[image]

**How do we upgrade a predicate to be part of an extension method and use it inside of our Linq clauses?**

Here's the model I am using:

```
public class BlobsPerContainerModel
{
    public string Container { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
var outgoingBlobsContainer = blobsPerContainer.Where((model) 
    => model.IsOutgoingContainer()).ToList();
```